# Adding PHP to background-image url

Tags: php, css, background-image

This is what I have so far but it's not working. This is my css:

```
background-image: url("upload/blog/'.$row["urlImg"].'");
```

Here is the full code:

```
<?php 
  $stmt = $db->query
  ( 'SELECT blog.postID, blog.postTitle, blog.postSlug, blog.postDesc, blog.urlImg, blog.postTags, blog.postDate
     FROM blog, blog_post_cats
     WHERE blog.postID = blog_post_cats.postID AND blog_post_cats.catID = 4 ORDER BY postID DESC LIMIT 1'
  ); 
  while($row = $stmt->fetch())
  {
    echo '<article style="background-image: url(upload/blog/'.$row['urlImg'].'" );"> '; 
  }
?>
```

This PHP `echo` does not work.

[clicke to view output screenshot ,the blank space is the error ,others are url images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ELmBw.png)

Comment: Did you forget to add your code?  Please [edit] your question.

Comment: I think the problem is improperly escaped quotes.

Comment: You need to edit your question to also show how you get `$row["urlImg"]` If its returning blank then the query (assuming since you are using `$row`) maybe be returning blank or you might be fetching it wrong

Comment: You should frequently close `<?php  ?> ` tags to output HTML tags and reopen only for printing variables. Does `the_field()` output something or are you missing an `echo` statement?

Comment: The first code snippet and the "full" code differ from each other. Unclear what is what.

Comment: code work perfectly with` '<img alt="" src="upload/blog/'.$row["urlImg"].'">';` buh couldnt work with background-image

Comment: @Quasimodo'sclone the first code is **background-image: url("upload/blog/'.$row["urlImg"].'");** must be a typing error

Comment: There is an attribute `style="background-image: url("`. You cannot have the same qoutes in CSS as you already used in HTML. That's why I said you should write plain HTML after closing PHP tags.

Comment: Can you show us the `html` displayed on output when it "doesn't work"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thank y'all for your contributions

i got this myself

i just added my website address to it @`https://mywebsite.com/upload/blog/...`

```
 echo '<article style="background-image: url(https://mywebsite.com/upload/blog/'.$row["urlImg"].'");"> ';
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you try to use double quotes in inline CSS, you actually are closing the HTML attribute `style="background-image: url("`. Use single quotes in this case of nested quotes. Rather than escaping single quotes in single-qouted `echo` strings, just close `<?php ?>` tags and write plain HTML.

```
<?php
  while($row = $stmt->fetch())
  {
?>
    <article class="latestPost excerpt big-1" style="background-image: url('upload/blog/<?php echo $row["urlImg"];?>');">

    </article>
<?php
  }
```

Comment: i cannot us that simply because the code is run inside a query `<?php $stmt = $db->query('
    SELECT 
        blog.postID, blog.postTitle, blog.postSlug, blog.postDesc, blog.urlImg, blog.postTags, blog.postDate 
    FROM 
        blog,
        blog_post_cats
    WHERE
         blog.postID = blog_post_cats.postID
         AND blog_post_cats.catID = 4
    ORDER BY 
        postID DESC LIMIT 1
    ');
    while($row = $stmt->fetch()){
echo '<article style="background-image: url(upload/blog/'.$row['urlImg'].'");">
                '; ?> `

Comment: What is the problem? You can close and reopen PHP tags almost everywhere.

Answer (score 1):

The problem are the double-quotes around the URL of the background image. The double quote after `url(` closes the `style` atrribute it's part of. So you should use escaped quotes inside the `url(...)` parenthesis:

```
echo '<article class="latestPost excerpt big-1" style="background-image: url(\"upload/blog/'.$row["urlImg"].'\");"> ';
```

Answer (score 0):

Use double quote here...

```
     echo '<article style="background-image: url(upload/blog/'.$row["urlImg"].'");"> ';
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G5cYC.png)